# Can I specify a custom location for docker temporary files?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run docker in a partially locked-down environment, with /etc on a read-only mount point and a "/data" folder in a read/write mount point. I've added an /etc/docker/daemon.json file:

```
{
    "data-root": "/data/docker"
}
```

but dockerd is failing on startup with this error:

`failed to start daemon: Error saving key file: open /etc/docker/.tmp-key.json128868007: read-only file system`

Can I stop dockerd from trying to write into /etc? Are there best practices for running docker on a host with read-only mounts?

EDIT: Turns out there was only one file being written: /etc/docker/key.json which is talked about in detail [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7667). The .tmp-key.json bit is likely a part of some atomic file write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like only the "key.json" file is written to /etc. After some digging, I found [this PR](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/32587) which talks about making it configurable. As of docker 19.03.6, the option is still available for use in the daemon.json file as `"deprecated-key-path": "/path/to/file"`.